# Word match in multiple files

Tags: python, regex, file, file-io, python-3.x

I have a corpus of words like these. There are more than 3000 words. But there are 2 files:

```
File #1:
#fabulous       7.526   2301    2
#excellent      7.247   2612    3
#superb         7.199   1660    2
#perfection     7.099   3004    4
#terrific       6.922   629     1
#magnificent    6.672   490     1

File #2:
) #perfect      6.021   511     2
? #great        5.995   249     1
! #magnificent  5.979   245     1
) #ideal        5.925   232     1
day #great      5.867   219     1
bed #perfect    5.858   217     1
) #heavenly     5.73    191     1
night #perfect  5.671   180     1
night #great    5.654   177     1
. #partytime    5.427   141     1
```

I have many sentences like this, more than 3000 lines like below:

```
superb, All I know is the road for that Lomardi start at TONIGHT!!!! We will set a record for a pre-season MNF I can guarantee it, perfection.

All Blue and White fam, we r meeting at Golden Corral for dinner to night at 6pm....great
```

I have to go through every line and do the following task:
1) find if those corpus of words match anywhere in the sentences
2) find if those corpus of words match leading and trailing of sentences

I am able to do part 2) and not part 1). I can do it but finding a efficient way.
I have the following code:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
(id,num,senti,words) = re.split("\t+",line.strip())
sentence = re.split("\s+", words.strip().lower())

for line1 in f1: #f1 is the file containing all corpus of words like File #1
    (term2,sentimentScore,numPos,numNeg) = re.split("\t", line1.strip()) 
    wordanalysis["trail"] = found if re.match(sentence[(len(sentence)-1)],term2.lower()) else not(found)
    wordanalysis["lead"] = found  if re.match(sentence[0],term2.lower()) else not(found)

for line in sys.stdin:
  (id,num,senti,words) = re.split("\t+",line.strip())
  sentence = re.split("\s+", words.strip().lower())

for line1 in f1: #f1 is the file containing all corpus of words like File #1
  (term2,sentimentScore,numPos,numNeg) = re.split("\t", line1.strip()) 
  wordanalysis["trail"] = found if re.match(sentence[(len(sentence)-1)],term2.lower()) else not(found)
  wordanalysis["lead"] = found  if re.match(sentence[0],term2.lower()) else not(found)

for line1 in f2: #f2 is the file containing all corpus of words like File #2
  (term2,sentimentScore,numPos,numNeg) = re.split("\t", line1.strip())
  wordanalysis["trail_2"] = found if re.match(sentence[(len(sentence)-1)],term.lower()) else not(found)
  wordanalysis["lead_2"] = found  if re.match(sentence[0],term.lower()) else not(found)
```

Am I doing this right? Is there a better way to do it.

Comment: What about using the data strcuctrue *Hashes* in *Redis*? Firstly, read the data from the two files into Redis stored in *Hashes*. Then when reading a word from a sentence, do a hash search in Redis which could be very fast. This may be help [hash command in redis](http://redis.io/commands#hash)

Comment: @flyer Is that like Hashtable in java?

Comment: Sorry for that I have little knowledge about Java. This is a brief explanation: [the little redis book](https://github.com/karlseguin/the-little-redis-book/blob/master/en/redis.md#hashes)

Answer (score 0):

this is a classic map reduce problem, if you want to get serious about efficiency you should consider something like: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

and if you are too lazy / have too few resources to set your own hadoop environment you can try a ready made one http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/

feel free to post your code here after its done :) it will be nice to see how it is translated into a mapreduce algorithm...

Comment: Hi, yes it is. I am glad you noticed. This problem is map-reduce algorithm, it has a reducer script too & have hadoop setup for this but using a efficient data structure is important too.